# How to retry on response timeout with Spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webclient

I'm having trouble understanding how to configure my web client to retry in case of a response timeout. Below code works fine when the server returns a 5xx error, but I'm unable to handle the error when there is no response. I'm also not able to find any info related to this in the [Spring Webclient docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client).

I've setup a MockWebServer like this

```
    MockWebServer mockBackEnd = new MockWebServer();
    mockBackEnd.start();
    mockBackEnd.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("TestBody").setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.NO_RESPONSE));
    mockBackEnd.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("OK"));
```

The client and the call to the mock server

```
    String baseUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%s?", mockBackEnd.getPort());
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
            .build();

    webClient
                .get()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body ->
                                new HttpServerErrorException(response.statusCode(), body))
                )
                .bodyToMono(CustomResponse.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof HttpServerErrorException)
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof ReadTimeoutException)
                )
                .block();
```

The resulting exception on timeout is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
```

How can I get the code above to retry not only on 5xx errors but on timeout errors as well?

Comment: Filtering on that should  give you what you need, i.e. filter on `WebClientRequestException` and then check the nested cause. The filter apply on the exact exception, not a nested cause it might contain.

Answer (score 4):

I got a response [over on Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot?at=62109db40909252318e85c49) which pointed me to the fact that you can only have a single filter in the retryWhen. That in combination with the response from Stephane Nicoll to my original post finally solved the issue. (Note that the last `instanceof` here checks for `io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException` and not `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` which is thrown in case you set a specific timeout on the request level)

Final working code:

```
String baseUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%s?", mockBackEnd.getPort());
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
            .build();

    webClient
                .get()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body ->
                                new HttpServerErrorException(response.statusCode(), body))
                )
                .bodyToMono(CustomResponse.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(5, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                            .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof HttpServerErrorException ||
                                    throwable instanceof WebClientRequestException && throwable.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException)
                    )
                .block();
```